# Searching any table for any field in procedure Dynamics Business Central AL

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al, businesscentral

I'm working on optimizing some **AL** code in *Dynamics Business Central*, and I've noticed that there's a lot of redundant code when searching for records based on specific fields like name or age. I'd like to refactor this into a more generic function that can handle searching any table for any field.

```
procedure findEmployeeNo(Name:Text[20]; Age:Integer): code[20]
begin
            // search by Name
            Employee.Reset();
            Employee.ChangeCompany(company.Name);
            Employee.Setrange("Name", Name);
            If Employee.FindFirst() then begin
                exit(Employee."No.")
            end;
            // search by Age
            Employee.Reset();
            Employee.Setrange("Age", Age);
            If Employee.FindFirst() then begin
                exit(Employee."No.")
            end;
    exit('');
end;
```

```
procedure findEmployeeNo(Name:Text[20]; Age:Integer): code[20]
var Employee: record Employee;
begin
            Employee := findFieldData('Employee', 'Name', Name)
            If Employee then begin
                exit(Employee."No.")
            end;
            Employee := findFieldData('Employee', 'Age', Age)
            If Employee then begin
                exit(Employee."No.")
            end;
    exit('');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `RecRef/FieldRef` data types and record variable of `Field` table.

But why? This will not give you any performance (probably the opposite), it will make code less readable and less searchable using tools like Statical Prism.

To much cons and not a single pro for this approach. Not worth it imho.

Comment: Thanks for paving the path by using two RecRef/FieldRef data types!

Comment: I wish you don't follow that path 